# GAE golang templates stopped working

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, go

I've been successfully using go for months - last night my app started 404 page not found errors but only on pages that use Templates.  Those that don't  use the Template system work fine.
I re-installed the Go sdk and discovered that the Guestbook demo ( also uses Templates)  doesn't work either.  ... and then I noticed that links to the log files weren't appearing on the Instance page of  the dev console - but when I click the "default" link it displayed the guestbook templated page that I had just requested and got the 404.

It seems that the system can't find template folder and that is causing the 404s

My configuration seems to have broken and I haven't been able to figure out why - hope someone can help...

...After messing with environment variables and stuff for a while with no success,  I ran "test_Python" file. These all generated Errors: test_too_big_rewrite, module_test, python_sandbox_test all generated errors - the process hung up on "test_serve"

This is causing my problems?  Is there a way to correct?  Uninstall and reinstall Python?  Will I have to uninstall/reinstall Go SDK  ? 
thanks!

Comment: Confirm the location in your config is consistent with the files location on the server. I don't think you're going to get much more help on SO, the format is not particularly useful for troubleshooting env specific config problems.

Answer (score 0):

I re-installed Python (the module_test and other tests failed) and updated the gae-go sdk.  This fixed my problem.  I believe that a recently identified Flash exploit had something to do with it as I experienced a number of Flash crashes in web page ads just before the problems began.